# Kubectl apply for a deployment with revHistoryLimit 0 does not delete the old replica set

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Here is my deploment template:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    name: XXX
    version: {{ xxx-version }}
    deploy_time: "{{ xxx-time }}"
  name: XXX
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit : 0
  strategy:
    type : "RollingUpdate"
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable : 0%
      maxSurge : 100%
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: XXX
      version: {{ xxx-version }}
      deploy_time: "{{ xxx-time }}"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: XXX
        version: {{ xxx-version }}
        deploy_time: "{{ xxx-time }}"
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: docker-registry:{{ xxx-version }}
        name: XXX
        ports:
        - name: XXX
          containerPort: 9000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key section in the documentation that's relevant to this issues is:

> Existing Replica Set controlling Pods whose labels match `.spec.selector`but whose template does not match `.spec.template` are scaled down. Eventually, the new Replica Set will be scaled to `.spec.replicas` and all old Replica Sets will be scaled to 0.

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/

So the spec.selector should not vary across multiple deployments:

```
selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: XXX
      version: {{ xxx-version }}
      deploy_time: "{{ xxx-time }}"
```

should become:

```
selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: XXX
```

The rest of the labels can remain the same